# Apache sending error file after every request

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

We've got a problem with my apache2 here, which seems kind of hard to debug... or: to understand in the first place.

Our environment is Debian Wheezy + Apache2 + mod_perl + Mason.

The problem is, that apache, even, if I try to get an empty site, sends an error file *after* the file itself,

```
OK

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

But the file itself gets send. So lets say I have the index.html with just "hello" inside.

Every "gui browser" (that Ive tried yet, so Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera) just show hello, even in the source code theres nothing like that error. Theres no interpretation of mason or anything else going on there. It really seems, that most browsers totally ignore every other file, after the first one was sent (which is, in my opinion, perfectly fine), but I dont really understand how - and why - apache sends such things after the file itself was successfully created and sent.

But in the network logs (and in w3m and lynx) I see that error message below every file.

Apache does not log anything anywhere from which file or component this comes and we've already tried disabling anything like mod_rewrite and everything else, so, that just the "basic apache2 config" is in action and we disabled the autohandler and dhandlers of the directory of the file and upwards, but: Still it sends this message.

I know, my explaination is not very well, because I'm not an expert on this, but just maybe anyone has an idea of how that could be or at least, how I could try to see where that thing comes from.

Answer (score 0):

It is either mod_perl or Mason that produces the 500 error.

Show the configuration for mod_perl and the vhost it applies to, and somebody may be able to set you straight.